# Detach entity at doctrine pre* events

Tags: events, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to detach entity at (for example) prePersist event?

```
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    $em->detach($entity);
}
```

In this way entity will not be detached.  `prePersist` function is in the service:

```
abc.saver:
      class: App\AbcBundle\Layer\Saver
      arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
      tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

P.S. I resolved this using `onFlush` event:

```
foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity)
{
    $em->detach($entity);

}
```

but I am interesting how can I reach this using doctrine `pre*` behaviors (Lifecycle Events)?

Comment: do you finally found the solution? I'm getting the same problem

Comment: Seems no. But I do not remember exactly

Comment: @tuchk4 `onFlush` event works perfectly for me, thanks!

Comment: I used the `onFlush` event as well even if it is a bit less convenient, because detaching in a `prePersist` event was unreliable (I am using Doctrine ODM, not the ORM).